# Javascript - code not stoping in then

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to expand my knowledge (beginner stage). Basically, I would like to use promises to write new email to my user. I have some code base in my play ground project, but my function is not stopping on then.
This is the function that should write to Database:

```
changeEmailAddress(user, newEmail) {
       new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            user.setEmail(newEmail);
            userRepository.saveUser(user).then(() => {
                return resolve();
            }).catch(e => {
                return reject(e);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

And if I am not mistaken, this is how I should use it:

```
changeEmailAddress(user, "hello@there.com").then(function () {

    //it never comes in here :(
})
```

I have similar functions working on the user, but my function is not coming in to 'then'

Comment: If this is your actual code, then the `changeEmailAddress(...).then(` part should generate a run-time error such as "undefined.then is not a function". Does it? That would have been a **big** hint as to what was going wrong.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're committing the [explicit promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Your code need be no more complicated than

```
changeEmailAddress(user, newEmail) {
  user.setEmail(newEmail);
  return userRepository.saveUser(user);
}
```

Making sure, of course, to not forget the `return`!

Answer (score -2):

your function changeEmailAddress return nothing, that's why

```
changeEmailAddress(user, newEmail) {
   let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        user.setEmail(newEmail);
        userRepository.saveUser(user).then(() => {
            return resolve();
        }).catch(e => {
            return reject(e);
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are not returning the new Promise.

```
changeEmailAddress(user, newEmail) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        user.setEmail(newEmail);
        userRepository.saveUser(user).then(() => {
            resolve();
        }).catch(e => {
            reject(e);
        });

    });
}
```

You may also have an unhandled rejection.

```
changeEmailAddress(user, "hello@there.com").then(function () {
    //it never comes in here :(
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e); // Does this happen?
})
```

EDIT: Your changeEmailAddress uses the anti-pattern (see @torazburo's answer). Although this answer works, you should just return your saveUser promise unless you want to directly work with the result of it.

Comment: I hane not tested does it stop there. I need to handle that somehow.

Comment: This answer, including the code in the question is implementing the anti-pattern that torazaburo mentions in his answer; his answer is the one that should be marked as an answer not to promote the use of anti-patterns.